# Javascript - Count the number of instances of a particular string from a variable

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble getting my code to count the number of times the word 'Yes' appears in a variable.  It works if I replace the variable with the string 'YesYesYes.'  The result is 3.  I want to do the same, but from a variable instead.

Here is my code.

```
function getAllAnswers() {
    var var_allAnswers = document.querySelector('input[name="Q1"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q2"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q3"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q4"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q5"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q6"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q7"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q8"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q9"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q10"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q11"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q12"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q13"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q14"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q15"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q16"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q17"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q18"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q19"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q20"]:checked').value;
    document.getElementById("AllAnswers").innerHTML = var_allAnswers;
}

function yesCount() {
    var var_yesCount = var_allAnswers.split("Yes").length - 1;
    document.getElementById("YesCount").innerHTML = var_yesCount;
}

function noCount() {
    var var_noCount = var_allAnswers.split("No").length - 1;
    document.getElementById("NoCount").innerHTML = var_noCount;
}
```

Here is my markup.

```
    <button onclick="yesCount()">Yes Count</button><br/>
    Yes Count: <p id="YesCount"></p><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="noCount()">No Count</button><br/>
    No Count: <p id="NoCount"></p><br/><br/>
    All Answers: <p id="AllAnswers"></p><br/><br/>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You may need to remove the keyword var in your getAllAnswers() to make var_allAnswers a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `var_allAnswers` called in the `yesCount` and `noCount` functions is out of scope, meaning it's inaccessible to your functions. A somewhat hackish fix:

```
(function()
{
    var var_allAnswers;

    function getAllAnswers() {
        var_allAnswers = document.querySelector('input[name="Q1"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q2"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q3"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q4"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q5"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q6"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q7"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q8"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q9"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q10"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q11"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q12"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q13"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q14"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q15"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q16"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q17"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q18"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q19"]:checked').value + document.querySelector('input[name="Q20"]:checked').value;
        document.getElementById("AllAnswers").innerHTML = var_allAnswers;
    }

    function yesCount() {
        var var_yesCount = var_allAnswers.split("Yes").length - 1;
        document.getElementById("YesCount").innerHTML = var_yesCount;
    }

    function noCount() {
        var var_noCount = var_allAnswers.split("No").length - 1;
        document.getElementById("NoCount").innerHTML = var_noCount;
    }
})();
```

Though you should really be passing the `var_allAnswers` variable around in your function calls as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `var_allAnswers` you declared in `getAllAnswers()` can't be used in another function, instead you shoud declare your variable as **Global** or create a function that returns the variable to deal with. Ex:

```
var var_allAnswers;

function getAllAnswers() {
    var_allAnswers = document.querySelector('...
    document.getElementById("AllAnswers").innerHTML = var_allAnswers;
}

getAllAnswers();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a problem of scope here.
A var defines a varable which is available only in the block containing it { }
So, when you exit getAllAnswers() your variable var_allAnswers is discarded.

You need to reinitialize it before you could reuse it

```
function yesCount() {
    var_allAnswers = document.querySelector('input[name="Q1"]:checked').value
    var var_yesCount = var_allAnswers.split("Yes").length - 1 ;
    document.getElementById("YesCount").innerHTML = var_yesCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think it's a problem of scope. 
In the yesCount() and noCount() functions, the variable var_allAnswers cannot be referred. Marcel's answer is right. 
You may want to learn about the block scope in javascript. Here is an article about that:
http://danbeam.org/blog/2011/05/23/turns-out-there-is-block-scope-in-javascript-kinda/